# How to deserialize XML file into a list of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, serialization, deserialization

I need help , I have XML file that I already serialize upon a class called Class 1  that contain a list of another class type called "service" 
after serializing the list into XML file I am trying to DE-serialize the file Back into a list of service TYPE

this is class 1 code :

```
public class Class1

{
    public Class1()
    {
        ServiceList = new List<service>();

    }
    public List<service> ServiceList { get; set; }
}

public class service
{
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my serialization code:

```
 var filestream = new FileStream("sth.xml", FileMode.Create);
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(Class1)).Serialize(filestream,c);
        filestream.Close();
```

this is the XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Class1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<ServiceList>
<service>
  <ServiceName>cool</ServiceName>
  <Symbol>v</Symbol>
</service>
<service>
  <ServiceName>cool</ServiceName>
  <Symbol>v</Symbol>
</service>
<service>
  <ServiceName>cool</ServiceName>
  <Symbol>v</Symbol>
</service>
<service>
  <ServiceName>cool</ServiceName>
  <Symbol>v</Symbol>
</service>
<service>
  <ServiceName>cool</ServiceName>
  <Symbol>v</Symbol>
</service>
<service>
  <ServiceName>cool</ServiceName>
  <Symbol>v</Symbol>
</service>
<service>
  <ServiceName>cool</ServiceName>
  <Symbol>v</Symbol>
</service>
<service>
  <ServiceName>cool</ServiceName>
  <Symbol>v</Symbol>
</service>
<service>
  <ServiceName>cool</ServiceName>
  <Symbol>v</Symbol>
</service>
<service>
  <ServiceName>cool</ServiceName>
  <Symbol>v</Symbol>
</service>
 </ServiceList>
</Class1>
```

and this is my De-serialization code which is running correctly but doesn't give me the correct output

```
        XmlSerializer myDeserilizer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<service>) ,  new XmlRootAttribute("Class1"));
        FileStream myfilestream = new FileStream("sth.xml", FileMode.Open);
        var loadedData = (List<service>)myDeserilizer.Deserialize(myfilestream);
        myfilestream.Close();
```

the problem is am not getting the list after DE-serialization 
any help ??

Comment: Have you tried new XmlSerializer(typeof(Class1))? It should working

Comment: @Peyman you mean in the serialization code ?

Comment: no in Desrialize code,XmlSerializer myDeserilizer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Class1))

Comment: @Peyman i tried it , it gives me this Error : Unable to cast object of type 'WindowsFormsApplication4.Class1' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WindowsFormsApplication4.service]'.

Comment: Try my answer, it should be working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your code as follow and see the result:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Class1"), XmlType("Class1")]
public class Class1
{
  public Class1()
  {
     ServiceList = new List<service>();

  }
  [XmlElement(ElementName = "ServiceList")
  public List<service> ServiceList { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Service"), XmlType("Service")]
public class service
{
   [XmlElement(ElementName = "ServiceName")
   public string ServiceName { get; set; }

   [XmlElement(ElementName = "Symbol")
   public string Symbol { get; set; }
}
```

And then change your deserialize code as follow:

```
XmlSerializer myDeserilizer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Class1));
FileStream myfilestream = new FileStream("sth.xml", FileMode.Open);
var loadedData = myDeserilizer.Deserialize(myfilestream);
myfilestream.Close();
```

It should working, I tested in my local

Answer (score 0):

There is problem in your Deserialize past, you can simply change your deserialize part as bellow.

```
        XmlSerializer myDeserilizer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Class1));
        FileStream myfilestream = new FileStream("sth.xml", FileMode.Open);
        var loadedData = (Class1)myDeserilizer.Deserialize(myfilestream);
        var listOfServices = loadedData.ServiceList;
        myfilestream.Close();
```